# Office 365 document viewer - doesn't work with azure storage shared access url?

Tags: office365, azure-blob-storage, google-document-viewer

This neat url here will allow you to view any public/web accessible word, excel, powerpoint, etc. document can be viewed online:

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=URL_TO_YOUR_FILE

I have had success using it for documents stored in azure blob storage in containers with public access. But if I try to use a document url for a file that is in a private container (using a shared access signature url) I get an error that the file is not found.

Same issue with the google docs document viewer:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?

How can I get this working with private files (using shared access signature urls)?

**EDIT**

Interestingly, if I use a tinyurl URL created from the shared access signature, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get this working with private files (using shared access signature urls)?

According to your description, I tested it on my side and reproduced this issue. As [View Office documents in a browser](https://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/) mentioned that the  needs to be URL encoded, and the document must be publicly accessible on the internet.

For a simple way, you could create your online document URL via this [official tool](http://officewebviewer.com). Also, you could create the URL by yourself as follows:

`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=URLEncode(URL_TO_YOUR_FILE)`

Comment: Ok I'll try it. So to clarify you are saying if I url encode the shared access signature url it will work?

Comment: Yes, you could try it on your side.

Comment: Yes that works. So this issue was that it needed to be url encoded.

Comment: Ok it's working great for office files, but it doesn't seem to work with PDFs...I'm getting "File Not Found", "The URL of the original file is not valid or the document is not publicly accessible.
Verify the URL is correct, then contact the document owner." error...

Comment: Works mate.. My AWS presigned URL was also not working (15-min window public access). It's now working like a magic with an encoded URL.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a sample code for office documents preview in the browser (PPTX, XLXS, XLS, PPT, DOC , DOCX ) & PDF when Azure blob storage containers are private level access.

```
private static string GetContainerSharedAccessSignature(CloudBlockBlob blob, string fileName)
    {
        string contentType = "";
        var headers = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders
        {
            ContentDisposition = $"attachment;filename={fileName}",
        };

        if (fileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".docx"))
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".pptx"))
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".doc"))
            contentType = "application/msword";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".xls"))
            contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".ppt"))
            contentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".rtf"))
            contentType = "application/rtf";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".jpg"))
            contentType = "image/jpg";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".jpeg"))
            contentType = "image/jpeg";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".png"))
            contentType = "image/png";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".gif"))
            contentType = "image/gif";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".bmp"))
            contentType = "image/bmp";
        else if (fileName.Contains(".tif"))
            contentType = "image/tif";
        else
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType))
        {
            headers.ContentType = contentType;
        }

        var signature =
            blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(
                new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
                {
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
                },
                headers);

        return Uri.EscapeDataString($"{blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.AbsoluteUri}{signature}");
    }

  public string GenerateSASToken(string containerName, string fileName)
    {
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = null;
        try
        {
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = searchConfig.CloudBlobClient;
            cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            return GetContainerSharedAccessSignature(blob, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


 [HttpGet("bloburl/{fileName}/{container}")]
    public IActionResult BlobSASTokenURL(string fileName, string container)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"file name {fileName} is missing.");
                return UnprocessableEntity();
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(container))
            {
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"container name {fileName} is missing.");
                return UnprocessableEntity();
            }

            var tokenUrl = blobStorageService.GenerateSASToken(container, fileName);
            var token = new { tokenUrl };
            return Ok(token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, $"Failed to generate token url for {fileName} .");
        }
    }
```

> front end

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

    public getBlobSASUrl(fileName: string, containerName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.repository.get(environment.apiBaseURL, 'api/BlobStorage/sastoken/' + fileName + '/' + containerName)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => {
         return res.tokenUrl;
        }));


    }}
```

> Component

```
 import { UrlService } from './shared/search.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './filePreview.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: [ DatePipe ]
})
export class filePreviewComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private urlService: UrlService, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public datepipe: DatePipe) {

  }

     showFilePreview(fileName: string, containerName: string, fileContentType: string) {
    this.urlService.getBlobSASUrl(result.document.fileName, result.document.containerName).subscribe(results => {
          result.document.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src='+results+'&embedded=true');
          result.document.toggle =! result.document.toggle;
        });
  }

}
```

> HTML

```
  <div id="divpreview" class="preview_container_wrapper" *ngIf="result.document.toggle && result.document.containerName != null">
      <div class="col-md preview_container" id="dvpreviewcol">
        <iframe *ngIf="FileType !== 'PDF';"
          [src]='fileURL'
          class="preview_iframe"></iframe>
        <object *ngIf="FileType === 'PDF';" [data]="fileURL | safeUrl" type="application/pdf">Preview not available</object>
      </div>
    </div>
```